# Java xml digital signature validation

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature

I was trying to validate an XML signature.

The validation according to [this tutorial](http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/xml-digital-signature-api/using-the-java-xml-digital-signatur-2.html) works fine.

but i need to validate the XML using X509 Certificate public key instead of key value.but [most the examples they have used](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/dig_signature_api/) KeyStore class for validating the xml.

is this the only way to get x509 certificate public key to validate.but i need to validate the xml without using any keystore class/any JKS file

Comment: You know that you can include JKS or cer/pem files into a JAR file? Alternatively you can copy the file content into a static byte array and include the data into your code.

Comment: Hearty thanks for your help i have incude xmldsig.jar in my build path and i executed it....